# When compile llvm 3.1, why get error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm

For some reason, I need to install llvm 3.1 or llvm 3.0, but I'm getting this error when during `make`.

```
[  5%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/AsmMatcherEmitter.cpp.o
In file included from /home/ubuntu/llvm/utils/TableGen/AsmMatcherEmitter.cpp:103:0:
/home/ubuntu/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h: In member function ‘int llvm::PointerUnion3<PT1, PT2, PT3>::is() const’:
/home/ubuntu/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h:266:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
       return Ty(Val).is<T>();
                          ^
/home/ubuntu/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h:266:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       return Ty(Val).is<T>();
                            ^
/home/ubuntu/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h: In member function ‘T llvm::PointerUnion3<PT1, PT2, PT3>::get() const’:
/home/ubuntu/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h:279:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
       return Ty(Val).get<T>();
                           ^'
/home/ubuntu/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h:279:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       return Ty(Val).get<T>();
                             ^
```

I guess there might be a compatibility issue between llvm 3.0 and gcc 7.0.0, so I installed gcc-4.6.3, and use this `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/install -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$HOME/gcc463/install -L$HOME/gcc463/install" -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm` to configure. But the same error still occurs. Anybody knows why and how to fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm afraid asking people to install both a multigigabyte source tree and a new compiler is too much. Please reduce this to a minimal example, preferably without #define. I'll vote to close for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `-std=c++98` or if that does not work then `-std=c++11`. I'm afraid this maybe because of incompatibilities in different C++ versions.

Additionally, you may have to remove `-std=c++14` from the CXXFLAGS if it is there. This is the default for g++7.

> So I installed gcc-4.6.3, and use this

Did you change the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` flag so that **cmake** can use the **gcc-4.6** instead?

hth,

Comment: Yeah it turns out that I failed to pass the flags before. It worked after I did what you suggested. Thanks!